# Changing background color of selected item in recyclerview

Tags: android, background, android-recyclerview

How to change the background color of only selected view in my recycle view example?only the background color of clicked itemview needs to be changed.
Only one selected item must be displayed with background color change at a time and the rest needs to be as before selecting.
here is my code :

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView rv1;
    private  final String android_versions[]={
                "Donut",
                "Eclair",
                "Froyo",
                "Gingerbread",
                "Honeycomb",
                "Ice Cream Sandwich",
                "Jelly Bean",
                "KitKat",
                "Lollipop",
                "Marshmallow"
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
    }

    private  void initViews(){
        rv1=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
        rv1.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        rv1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        RecyclerDataAdapter rda=new RecyclerDataAdapter(rv1,getApplicationContext(),android_versions);
        rv1.setAdapter(rda);
    }
}
```

**RecyclerDataadapter**

```
public class RecyclerDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private String android_versionnames[];
    private Context context1;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


    public RecyclerDataAdapter(RecyclerView recylcerView,Context context,String android_versionnames[]){
        this.android_versionnames=android_versionnames;
        this.context1=context;
mRecyclerView=recylcerView;
        setHasStableIds(true);
        System.out.println("Inside dataadapter,Android names : \n ");
        for(int i=0;i<android_versionnames.length;i++){
            System.out.println("\n"+android_versionnames[i]);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tv1.setText(android_versionnames[position]);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return android_versionnames.length;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tv1;
        LinearLayout row_linearlayout;
        RecyclerView rv2;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv1=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
            row_linearlayout=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_linrLayout);
            rv2=(RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
            /*itemView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);//to transparent*/

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change @color for @drawable/shapecolored add shape

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Can be better, but it works.

```
int selectedPosition = -1;
int lastSelectedPosition = -1;
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
  holder.binding.getRoot().setOnClickListener(v -> {
    lastSelectedPosition = selectedPosition;
    selectedPosition = holder.getBindingAdapterPosition();
    notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedPosition);
    notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
  });
  if (selectedPosition == holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()) {
    holder.binding.linearLayout.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
  } else {
    holder.binding.linearLayout.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  }

}
```

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  ItemBinding binding;

  public ViewHolder(ItemBinding binding) {
    super(binding.getRoot());
    this.binding = binding;
  }
}
```

Comment: Bro the code is working perfectly but I'm getting an error when i change the color the text also change eg(0 index text (blue) 1 index text(black)) when changing black is shift to blue can you help me..

Comment: here how can we change the color of not selected items?

Comment: i don't think it's a very good idea to create new onclicklistener each time inside onbindViewholder.

Answer (score 14):

**A really simple way to achieve this would be:**

```
//instance variable
List<View>itemViewList = new ArrayList<>();

//OnCreateViewHolderMethod
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {    
    final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    final MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    itemViewList.add(itemView); //to add all the 'list row item' views

    //Set on click listener for each item view
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for(View tempItemView : itemViewList) {
                /** navigate through all the itemViews and change color
                of selected view to colorSelected and rest of the views to colorDefault **/
                if(itemViewList.get(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()) == tempItemView) {
                    tempItemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorSelected);
                }
                else{
                    tempItemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorDefault);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return myViewHolder;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The method above may ruin some default attributes of the itemView, in my case, i was using CardView, and the corner radius of the card was getting removed on click.

**Better solution:**

```
//instance variable
List<CardView>cardViewList = new ArrayList<>();

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cardView; //THIS IS MY ROOT VIEW
        ...

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.row_item_card);
            ...
        }
}

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final OurLocationObject locationObject = locationsList.get(position);
        ...

        cardViewList.add(holder.cardView); //add all the cards to this list

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //All card color is set to colorDefault
                for(CardView cardView : cardViewList){
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDefault));
                }
                //The selected card is set to colorSelected
                holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSelected));
            }
        });
}
```

**UPDATE 2 - IMPORTANT**

onBindViewHolder method is called multiple times, and also every time the user scrolls the view out of sight and back in sight!
This will cause the same view to be added to the list multiple times which may cause problems and minor delay in code executions!

***To fix this,***
**change**

```
cardViewList.add(holder.cardView);
```

**to**

```
if (!cardViewList.contains(holder.cardView)) {
    cardViewList.add(holder.cardView);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I can suggest this solution, which I used in my app. I've placed this code of onTouchListener in my ViewHolder class's constructor. **itemView** is constructor's argument. **Be sure to use *return false* on this method** because this need for working OnClickListener

```
itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
        {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Helps to maintain pressed state.

Answer (score 5):

Create Drawable file in Drawable foloder

```
<item android:drawable="@color/SelectedColor" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@color/SelectedColor" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@color/DefultColor"></item>
```

And in xml file

```
android:background="@drawable/Drawable file"
```

In RecyclerView onBindViewHolder

```
holder.button.setSelected(holder.button.isSelected()?true:false);
```

Like toggle button

Comment: What's prob tell me?@Anvi

Comment: @Joy it changes the color only for a bries moment.

Comment: THis should be the answer for other posts about making item looked like it was clicked!

Comment: @TDG adding `android:state_activated="true"` along with `android:state_selected` and setting both of them to true `onClick` could be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to change the selected view color like this. I think this is the SIMPLE WAY (because you don't have to create instance of layouts and variables.

MAKE SURE YOU DONT GIVE ANY BACKGROUND COLOR INSIDE YOUR RECYCLER VIEW's TAG.

```
holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8DFFFFFF"));
```

onBindViewHolder() method is given below

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.item_1.setText(list_items.get(position).item_1);
        holder.item_2.setText(list_items.get(position).item_2);
        holder.select_cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked){

                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8DFFFFFF"));
                }else {

                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I did to achieve this was actually taking a **static variable** to *store the last clicked position of the item* in the RecyclerView and then notify the adapter to update the layout at the position on the last clicked position i.e. notifyItemChanged(lastClickedPosition) whenever a new position is clicked. Calling **notifyDataSetChanged()** on the whole layout is very costly and unfeasible so doing this for only one position is much better.

Here's the code for this:

```
public class RecyclerDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private String android_versionnames[];
private Context mContext;
private static lastClickedPosition = -1; // Variable to store the last clicked item position


    public RecyclerDataAdapter(Context context,String android_versionnames[]){
        this.android_versionnames = android_versionnames;
        this.mContext = context;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,
                parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tv1.setText(android_versionnames[position]);    
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().
        getColor(R.color.cardview_light_background));
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                    
            v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().
            getColor(R.color.dark_background));
                if (lastClickedPosition != -1)
                    notifyItemChanged(lastClickedPosition);
                lastClickedPosition = position;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return android_versionnames.length;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tv1;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv1=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
        }
    }
}
```

So we will be actually updating only the intended item and not re-running unnecessary updates to the items which have not even been changed.

Answer (score 2):

If you use kotlin, it's really simple.

In your RecyclerAdapter class

```
userV.invalidateRecycler()

holder.card_User.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3eb1ae").withAlpha(60))
```

In your fragment or Activity

```
 override fun invalidateRecycler() {
    if (v1.recyclerCompanies.childCount > 0) {
        v1.recyclerCompanies.childrenRecursiveSequence().iterator().forEach { card ->
            if (card is CardView) {
                card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple solution to this, you don't have to work in the adapter. To change the background of a clicked item in the RecyclerView you need to catch the click in the adapter using an iterface:

```
interface ItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClickListener(item: Item, position: Int)
}
```

When we click we will get the item and the items position. In our bind function in the adapter we will set the on click listener:

```
container.setOnClickListener {
    onClickListener.onItemClickListener(item, position)
}
```

In your activity you will then implement this interface:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ItemAdapter.ItemClickListener {
```

Next we need to implement the background changing logic on item click. The logic is this: when the user clicks on an item, we check if the background on the clicked item is white (the item is not previously clicked) and if this condition is true, we change the background on all of the items in the RecyclerView to white (to invalidate previously clicked and marked items if there are any) and then change the background color of the clicked item to teal to mark it. And if the background of the clicked item is teal (which means the user clicks again on the same previously marked item), we change the background color on all of the items to white. First we will need to get our item background color as a ColorDrawable. We will use an iterator function to go through all of the items (children) of the RecyclerView and forEach() function to change the background on everyone of them. This method will look like this:

```
 override fun onItemClickListener(item: Item, position: Int) {
        val itemBackground: ColorDrawable =
            binding.recycler[position].background as ColorDrawable
        if (itemBackground.color == ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)) {
            binding.recycler.children.iterator().forEach { item ->
                item.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        this,
                        R.color.white
                    )
                )
            }
            binding.recycler[position].setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.teal_200)
            )
        } else {
            binding.recycler.children.iterator().forEach { item ->
                item.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        this,
                        R.color.white
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

So now you change the background on item click, if you click the same item, you will change the background back to what it was before.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
public static class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final MainActivity mParentActivity;
    private final List<DummyContent.DummyItem> mValues;
    private final boolean mTwoPane;
    private static int lastClickedPosition=-1;
    **private static View viewOld=null;**
    private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DummyContent.DummyItem item = (DummyContent.DummyItem) view.getTag();
            if (mTwoPane) {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, item.id);
                ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                mParentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                Context context = view.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, item.id);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

            **view.setBackgroundColor(mParentActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.SelectedColor));
            if(viewOld!=null)
                viewOld.setBackgroundColor(mParentActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.DefaultColor));
            viewOld=view;**
        }
    };
```

`viewOld` is `null` at the beginning, then points to the last selected view.
With `onClick` you change the background of the selected view and redefine the background of the penultimate view selected.
Simple and functional.

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter class make **Integer** variable as **index** and assign it to "0" (if you want to select 1st item by default, if not assign "-1").Then on your **onBindViewHolder** method,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.texttitle.setText(listTitle.get(position));
    holder.itemView.setTag(listTitle.get(position));
    holder.texttitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            index = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    if (index == position)
        holder.texttitle.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.selectedColor));
    else
        holder.texttitle.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.unSelectedColor));
}
```

Thats it and you are good to go.in **If** condition true section place your selected color or what ever you need, and else section place unselected color or what ever.

Answer (score 1):

Calling Notifydatasetchanged May be expensive when you need to change one item We can overcome by saving the old position and call notifyItemChanged

```
var old_postion=-1

   public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tv1.setText(android_versionnames[position]);

    holder.row_linearlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
       
            notifyItemChanged(old_position)
           //After item change happens set the old_postion as current position
            old_position=position
        }
    });
    if(old_position==position){
        holder.row_linearlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#567845"));
        holder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }
    else
    {
        holder.row_linearlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        holder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add click listener for item view in .onBindViewHolder() of your RecyclerView's adapter. get currently selected position and change color by .setBackground() for previously selected and current item

Comment: it works,but every recycler itemview gets selected..only one itemview must be selected at a time.what to do??

Answer (score 0):

Create a selector into Drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:state_pressed="true">
   <shape>
         <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
   </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape>
       <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Add the property into your xml (where you declare the RecyclerView):

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

Comment: It may have worked if you changed `android:state_pressed` with `android:state_selected`

Answer (score 0):

Most Simpler Way From My Side is to Add a variable in adapterPage as last Clicked Position.

in onBindViewHolder paste this code which checks for last stored position matched with loading positions
Constants is the class where i declare my global variables

```
if(Constants.LAST_SELECTED_POSITION_SINGLE_PRODUCT == position) {

    //change the view background here
    holder.colorVariantThumb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_background);
}

//on view click you store the position value and notifyItemRangeChanged will 
// call the onBindViewHolder and will check the condition

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        Constants.LAST_SELECTED_POSITION_SINGLE_PRODUCT=position;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mColorVariants.size());
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this from my Activity where i'm setting my Rv and not from the adapter

If someone need to do something similar here's the code

In this case the color changes on a logClick

```
           @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(UltimasConsultasActivity.this, "Item agregado a la lista de mails",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            sendMultipleMails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            valueEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            itemsSeleccionados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            listaEmails.add(superListItems.get(position));
            listaItems ="";
            NameOfyourRecyclerInActivity.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).NameOfYourViewInTheViewholder.setBackgroundColor((Color.parseColor("#336F0D")));

            for(int itemsSelect = 0; itemsSelect <= listaEmails.size() -1; itemsSelect++){

             listaItems  +=  "*"+listaEmails.get(itemsSelect).getDescripcion() + "\n";
            }

            itemsSeleccionados.setText("Items Seleccionados : "+  "\n" + listaItems);


        }


    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution**

**With my solution I'm not using notifyDataSetChanged(), because annoying whenever item is clicked, all the items from list got refreshed. To tackle this problem, I used notifyItemChanged(position); This will only change the selected item.**

Below I have added the code of my omBindViewHolder.

```
private int previousPosition = -1;
private SingleViewItemBinding previousView;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.viewBinding.setItem(itemList.get(position));
    holder.viewBinding.rlContainerMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clickRecyclerView.clickRecyclerItem(position, 0);

            previousPosition = position;
            notifyItemChanged(position);

            if(previousView != null){
                previousView.rlContainerMain.setBackgroundColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorGrayLight));

            }
        }
    });

    if(position == previousPosition){
        previousView = holder.viewBinding;

        holder.viewBinding.rlContainerMain.setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));

    }
    else {
        holder.viewBinding.rlContainerMain.setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorGrayLight));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the Kotlin you can do this simply:
all you need is to create a static variable like this:

```
companion object {
     var last_position = 0
}
```

then in your **onBindViewHolder** add this code:

```
holder.item.setOnClickListener{
        holder.item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_item)
        notifyItemChanged(last_position)
        last_position=position
    }
```

which item is the child of recyclerView which you want to change its background after clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

I made this implementation in kotlin I thing is not very efficient but works
ivIsSelected is a ImageView that represent in my case a check mark

```
var selectedItems = mutableListOf<Int>(-1)

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ContactViewHolder, position: Int) {
    // holder.setData(ContactViewModel, position)  // I'm passing this to the ViewHolder
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)   
    holder.itemView.ivIsSelected.visibility = INVISIBLE
    selectedItems.forEach {
        if (it == position) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(45, 0, 255, 43))
            holder.itemView.ivIsSelected.visibility = VISIBLE
        }
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { it ->
        it.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)  
        selectedItems.add(position)
        selectedItems.forEach { selectedItem ->  // this forEach is required to refresh all the list
            notifyItemChanged(selectedItem)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A faster and simpler way is saving the previous *View* element selected, so you don't have to use *notifyDataSetChanged()* or *notifyItemChanged(position)*.

First, add an instance variable inside your *Adapter (RecyclerDataAdapter)*:

```
View prevElement;
```

Then, inside your function *onClick()* (or in my case the lambda function version) you insert this:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    // CODE TO INSERT
    if (prevElement != null)
         prevElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.selected);
    prevElement = v;
    // DO SOMETHING
    ...
});
```

As you can see, the first thing done is checking if the *prevElement* is not *null* (an element was clicked before this), so we change its background color to *Color.TRANSPARENT* (even if it's the same element clicked twice). Then, we set the background color of the *View* element clicked (*v*) is changed to *R.color.selected*. Finally set the element clicked to the *prevElement* variable, so it can be modified in the next click action.

Answer (score 0):

The response from @Sudhanshu Vohra above was the best in my case and much simpler.
I did minor changes to handle the new selection and previous selection to adjust the display.

I modified it as:

```
     //Handle selected item and previous selection
       if (lastSelectedIndex != -1) {
             notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedIndex);
        }

        notifyItemChanged(bindingAdapterPosition);
       lastSelectedIndex = bindingAdapterPosition;
```

Now I refresh only two items, rather than the entire list and it works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a simple way to do it ,

```
        if (position == selectedItemPosition) {
            holder.textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.appColorPrimary));
//          // Change to desired color for selected item
        } else {
            holder.textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.appColorSecondary));
//          // Default color for non-selected items
        }
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                onClickCity.onClick(name);
                if (position == selectedItemPosition) {
                    holder.textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.appColorPrimary));
                } else {
                    holder.textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.appColorSecondary));
//                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                notifyItemChanged(selectedItemPosition);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                selectedItemPosition=position;
//                holder.textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_user_profile_white_background);
            }
        });
```

> You can change appColorPrimary and secondary as your color, and use
> setBackgroundResource() for background change

Answer (score -1):

I got it like this

```
public void onClick(View v){
        v.findViewById(R.id.textView).setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.selector_row);
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: This will not revert the background color of other items.

Comment: @AnupSharma It will change the background color of the selected Item and that is what he asked to be done.

Answer (score -2):

я не знаю на сколько это поможет но я типа так сделал:) в адаптере @Override public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder holder, int position) { holder.bind(sortedList.get(position)); holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bacground_button); }