# Recycler view item colour change repeating after scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Recycler view item color change repeating after scrolling.

I used to change color at a particular position of the Recyclerview list. When scrolling occurs another item at the bottom has the same change. And it is repeating in pattern. How to resolve this?

```
 holder.recycle_Listing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemListener.connectionClicked(v,position, itemtype);

            holder.mainlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e927a4d1"));

        }
    });
```

Comment: you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692214/changing-background-color-of-selected-item-in-recyclerview

Comment: please provide more code from your adapter, as for your after scrolling it changes color, ofcourse it is the view is recreated with the same position as the position that you clicked.

Comment: yes, i found solution for that @AchmadNaufalSyafiq . Thanks for the response.

Comment: @AndroidSurya the link was helpful to find answer but not the proper one for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saved every item keys in an array and  that selected array also passed through my Adapter class. Even simple colour change works fine in this format. Here the code is changed as per my the requirement.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ICConversationHomeAddConnectionsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        JsonObject object = dataArray.get(position).getAsJsonObject();
        if(selectedArray.contains(object.get("userkey").getAsString()))
        {
            GradientDrawable borCol = new GradientDrawable();
            borCol.setCornerRadius(7);
            borCol.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            borCol.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor("#60B9E1"));
            holder.recycle_Listing.setBackgroundDrawable(borCol);
           //holder.mainlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e927a4d1"));
        }
        else
        {
            GradientDrawable borCol = new GradientDrawable();
            borCol.setCornerRadius(7);
            borCol.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            borCol.setStroke(1, Color.parseColor("#e0e0e0"));
            holder.recycle_Listing.setBackgroundDrawable(borCol);
          //holder.mainlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f1f1f1"));
        }


            holder.profileName.setText(object.get("name").getAsString());

        holder.recycle_Listing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                holder.mainlayout.setSelected(!holder.mainlayout.isSelected());

                if (holder.mainlayout.isSelected()) {
                    GradientDrawable borCol = new GradientDrawable();
                    borCol.setCornerRadius(7);
                    borCol.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    borCol.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor("#60B9E1"));
                    holder.recycle_Listing.setBackgroundDrawable(borCol);
                  //  holder.mainlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#11B5DA"));
                } else {
                    GradientDrawable borCol = new GradientDrawable();
                    borCol.setCornerRadius(7);
                    borCol.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    borCol.setStroke(1, Color.parseColor("#e0e0e0"));
                    holder.recycle_Listing.setBackgroundDrawable(borCol);
                   // holder.mainlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f1f1f1"));
                }



                itemListener.connectionClicked(v,position, itemtype);


               //holder.mainlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#11B5DA"));
              //holder.mainlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f1f1f1"));
            }
        });



    }
```

This code works fine with no repeated colour change in recycler. If any queries feel free to ask via comments or chat

Answer (score 5):

The recycler view recycles the view in OnBindViewHolder.So when items are clicked it gets reflected in some other positions.To solve this. create a global SparseBooleanArray to store the clicked position.

```
private final SparseBooleanArray array=new SparseBooleanArray();
```

Then inside final viewholder add the clickListener and onClick store the position of the clicked item.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public YOURVIEW view;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        view = (YOURVIEW) v.findViewById(R.id.YOURVIEWID);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                array.put(getAdapterPosition(),true);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in inside OnBindViewHolder,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if(array.get(position)){
        holder.mainlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e927a4d1"));
    }else{
        holder.mainlayout.setBackgroundColor(UNSELECTEDCOLOR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe many items can be clicked so only `mItemSelected ` is not enough.

Comment: then use sparseBoolean Array.Check the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set your background color in `void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position);` such as

```
List<Integer> selectedPosition = new ArrayList(yourDataSize);
void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position){

     if(selectedPosition.get(position) == 1){
       holder.mainlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e927a4d1"));
     }else {
       holder.mainlayout.setBackgroundColor(normalColor);
     }

     //when the item clicked 
     selectedPosition.add(position,1);

}
```

Comment: what is Data class?

Comment: found solution and posted here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That function returns relative position not absolute so when screen is scrolled position is replaced with a new value. use position from your list for the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to recycling of viewholder of recycler view. Try this
It worked for me.

```
public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.setIsRecyclable(false);


    }
```

Comment: I do not think it's a good idea because recycler view is used for caching.

Comment: disabled the purpose of recycler with this code?. It is not an acceptable method.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement this method in your adapter class, may be it's solve your problem

```
@Override
    public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolderProduct holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        holder.mainlayout.removeAllViews();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview & Room Database in Kotlin.

in Activity:  //to send position to Adapter

```
val putPosition = 5   // what you want to be position
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
       (Recyclerview.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(putPosition-1,0)
}, 1500)
//
//
// out of onCreate (for companion)
fun getVersePosition() = putPosition
```

in Adapter:    // to get position from Activity

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Adapter.Holder, position: Int) {
    val roomData = listData[position]
    holder.setRoomData(roomData)
    val activity : MainActivity.Companion = MainActivity
    val getPosition : Int? = activity.companionMainActivity?.getVersePosition()
    if (position == getPosition-1){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AFB42B"))
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        }
}
```

SparseBooleanArray() doesn't need
and bind doesn't need too.

But it's very important

```
holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

If omitted, repetition will occur.