# RecyclerView lost its item position when scrolled

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I'm currently working on `RecyclerView` implementation on my project. When I set item on `RecyclerView` and scroll, I lost its position.

I Use Some if and else condition to click and change the color of text but its change when I'll not scroll the `RecyclerView` item.
Please suggest me the right way how to handle this condition.

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListner(new LoadVehicleTypeAdapter.setOnitemclick() {
@Override
public void ImageClick(int position, String Name,String Description,int id) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = null;
    CustomTextView customTextView = null;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rvVehicleTypes.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.root1);
            customTextView = (CustomTextView) rvVehicleTypes.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.frag_cartypes_inflated_name);
            if (i==position) {
                linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
                customTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));


            } else {
                linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
                customTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));
            }
        }
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),Name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}

});
```

Comment: can't suggest anything without seeing code

Comment: @Vivek I'll Update the code on the question.

Comment: refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46932217/1848157

Comment: @Radhey Same Problem in my side which you will be mentioned in commented URL but in my case, I'll change the color of the text in the click. Right now I have no option to solve the problem please tell me?

Comment: You can try this link to solve the bug [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53664672/8348768]

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are new to the Android development world, with this assumption let me take you through the journey of ListView to RecyclerView.

ListView, we were used to follow ViewHolder pattern to manage items being recycled when you scroll the listview.

Now RecyclerView have that functionality in-built, not in-built but you have to implement it forcefully, I am talking about `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder`.

So now let's take one step ahead in understanding how it works, as soon as you start scrolling down the list, inflated item views start getting recycled, with that your previously inflated ViewHolder (which gets actually created in onCreateViewHolder) is reused.

Now to solve this issue, you have to remember the position and for the same most of us used to use `SparseBooleanArray`

Comment: @ Paresh I'll also create a Recycle view  Adapter class which include onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolde.The problem occurs when I scroll recycle view and that time I'll click 6th item then show click on 8th item  ?

Comment: @MohitLakhanpal now I am actually expecting you to complete the research on the words I have shared. you will get the solution!

Comment: I'm not changing the color of the text when use scroll view used otherwise it will work done for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documents of `RecyclerView`. Also I encourage you to read difference between `ListView` and `RecyclerView`

Are you using `RecyclerView` or `ListView`? From your code it seems that you are using `ListView`.

If you want to use `RecyclerView` please go through the tutorials.

Please go through [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html) tutorial. It will tell you how to use RecyclerView.
For click listener follow [this](http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-recyclerview-click-listener-tutorial/) tutorial.

Comment: this link did'nt help me please share another one with related to my problem

Comment: can you exactly tell me your requirement?

Comment: I'll use Recycle view to set an item horizontally and  I'll need to change the layout background color and text color on click the item.that was done sometime and sometime it will not change.

Comment: Use RecyclerView Manager as LinearLayoutManager with Horizontal.
To change color, change color in `BindViewHolder()` Method. Also Use `ContextCompact.setColor` to change layout color.

Comment: I'll use this code to BindViewHolder() method but it will not change the color or background when it is in if the condition          if(I==position){
          
            holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
            holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
        else
        {

            holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
            holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));

        }

Comment: Instead of `Color.parseColor`, use `ContextCompact.setColor()` method