# Cannot change the background color of selected items of recycler

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to highlight the selected items in `recyclerview`. I can count the number of items selected. 
I want the highlighting as

[image].....

I have tried this code.

```
     recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            if (isMultiSelect) {
                multi_select(position);
                selectedPositon = position;
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Details Page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }

            if (selectedPositon == position) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e2a49e"));
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f5f5f5"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            if (!isMultiSelect) {
                selected_list = new ArrayList<AlertListItem>();
                isMultiSelect = true;
                selectedPositon = position;
                if (mActionMode == null) {
                    mActionMode = startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                }
            }

            if (selectedPositon == position) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e2a49e"));
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f5f5f5"));
            }
            multi_select(position);
        }
    }));
}
```

can someone help me out.

Comment: Show your full binding code..

Comment: sorry, I am new to android, what is bindup code means...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing background color of selected item in recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692214/changing-background-color-of-selected-item-in-recyclerview)

Comment: @kondarahul post your full code of `RecycleView extend Adapter` code.

Comment: are you using custom adapter??

Comment: i am using custom adapter for fectching data.i used above code in MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

```
           if (btn.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(itemView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.understand_clicked).getConstantState())) {
                btn.setBackground(itemView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.understand_not_clicked));          

         } else {
                btn.setBackground(itemView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.understand_clicked));                   
            }
```

Do this code in a custom recyclerviewadapter, in View holder class. Use **getConstantState** for current state of image. You can also change color of selected raw.

Answer (score 0):

you can use use below code

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(array[position]);

        holder.row_linearlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                index=position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        if(index==position){
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff8569"));
            holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
        else
        {
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

    }
```

HolderClass

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        LinearLayout layout;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            layout=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.layouot_linear);
            recyclerView=(RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        }
    }
```