# How can I change the color of the unselected and selected items on a RecyclerView on click?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a RecyclerView adapter that sets the icon for every item on the list. Here's the adapter class

```
package m.e.myapplication

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.calculator_cost_currency_type_item.view.*

class CurrencyTypeAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<CurrencyTypeViewHolder>() {

private val currencyTypeList = listOf(R.drawable.icon_currency_dollar, R.drawable.icon_currency_euro, R.drawable.icon_currency_lira)

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return currencyTypeList.size
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CurrencyTypeViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.calculator_cost_currency_type_item, parent, false)
    return CurrencyTypeViewHolder(cellForRow)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CurrencyTypeViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currencyTypeItem = currencyTypeList[position]

    holder.itemView.currencyTypeItemCostImageViewCCF.setImageResource(currencyTypeItem)
}
}

class CurrencyTypeViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
}
```

Here's how it's being called from the MainActivity

```
package m.e.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    currencyTypeRecyclerViewCCF.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    currencyTypeRecyclerViewCCF.adapter = CurrencyTypeAdapter()
    }
}
```

I would like to have code that changes the color of the layout corresponding to the selected item, as well as code that changes the color of the unselected items. Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at this [Changing the background color of the selected item in recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40712773/5912570)

Answer (score 0):

First of all create string type variable name it `selectedposition`
`var selectedposition=""`in your `CurrencyTypeAdapter` class

Now add position tag to your `itemview`
`holder.itemview.tag="$position" //this is for to identify the itemview`

Now add onClick listener to your itemview in `onBindViewHolder` method
`holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{`
     `selectedposition="$position"`
      `notifyDataSetChanged()`
`}`

Now in onBindViewHolder method
  `if(selectedposition.equal("$position")){ //this is your selected item do what you want }`