# How to darken CardView using onClick?

Tags: java, android

This is my first time asking a question here, so apologies if I do something wrong.

I have been using [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrnPJCHvNZuBtTYUuc5Pyo4V7xZ2HNtf4) to make a RecyclerView in my app, with individual CardViews. I want to make it so that when a cardview is clicked, it will change the card to a slightly dark gray, to indicate that it was clicked. However, I don't know how to go about doing this. If someone could help me, that would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: see this answer.it is yours :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/40712773/11586761

Comment: But do you mean changing color for good or something like Ripple effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `setOnClickListener` method, you have to add

`card.setCardBackgroundColor(colorYouWant);`

and you can add it directly to the onBindViewHolder in the adapter class of the RecycleView.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for this! I had created a sample cardview that would be used for the recylerview, but the cardview itself didn't have an id, so I couldn't access it. Hopefully this comment might help others who had this as well.

Answer (score 0):

On onclick() method you just  have to change card background color. You can do this by this command.

```
card.setCardBackgroundColor(color);
```