# how to set color the selected Item of Recycler View From Activity?

Tags: android

I have a Recycler View. Actually what I need is when I click any item in Recycler View that Item must get color and when I click another item I want that the first one become normal from an Activity

Comment: And what code have you written for that? There is no one who can help you without some useful code. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing background color of selected item in recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692214/changing-background-color-of-selected-item-in-recyclerview)

Comment: No this link not useful

Comment: @gtxtreme Actually i have recycler adapter and i want to update item background color from MainActivity.kt

Comment: You need to add a "isSelected = true/false" state for your item in adapter. When it's selected change color.